# Perl script to compare two files

Tags: perl

I am new to Perl, and I need to write a Perl script to compare two files which shows the matched and unmatched content in the output file. I am supposed to pass the those two files as parameters.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do your own homework.

Comment: exec (diff => -y => @ARGV); # :-)

Comment: Or, if you're not going to do your own homework, at least show you've made some effort to solving this yourself.

Answer (score 5):

There are at least the following modules that could be coopted to produce the result:

- [Text::Diff](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::Diff)
- [Algorithm::Diff](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Algorithm::Diff)

The latter is about a decade old, so the former (updated last year) is a better bet.  There are other algorithms out the on CPAN too - [Algorithm::LCS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Algorithm::LCS) might be interesting were it not also most of a decade old.  Generally, with Perl, the secret is to find someone else who has already answered the question for you.

Of course, that may not sit so well with teachers at school or university.